# Does Slow spell allow a move and an action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, actions

Just looking for a clarification on what a target can do in a round when hit with [Slow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/slow) spell.

1. normally we get a 'move' and an 'action' (in addition to bonus etc)
2. my question is about just the two main things you can do in a round (move and action)
3. in pathfinder they had to choose between moving or taking a standard action
4. so trying to see how this compares
5. so could they move (with reduced speed) and then make one attack?
6. I am thinking that is the case
7. but in pathfinder they could not even do that, they could only move or attack

Comment: Welcome to the stack, gman, take the [tour] when you have a moment.

Answer (score 8):

You are right that they can both move and attack in the same turn, the only limitation to that is that they're moving at half speed. Having your speed reduced doesn't affect whether you can/can't move **unless** your movement is reduced to zero.

While it may have the same name, the spell is entirely different in Pathfinder vs. 5e. It's best to avoid assuming that what you know about a spell from one system translates over to the next.

Comment: thanks, i was hoping someone would tell me i was wrong; but anyway i appreciate the input...

Comment: Hahaha, I know the feeling of hoping that your initial impression is wrong, wish I could have helped!

Answer (score 3):

#### You may move and take an action.

*Slow* states:

> **An affected target's speed is halved**, it takes a −2 penalty to AC and Dexterity saving throws, and it can't use reactions. **On its turn, it can use either an action or a bonus action, not both.**

There is nothing here that limits an effected creature only one of movement or an action, so they may do both, though speed is halved. Notably, *there is no move action in 5th Edition*. This is one of the big differences from *Pathfinder 1e*. In 5e, moving up to your speed is just something you're allowed to do on your turn - the rules for ["Your Turn"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#YourTurn) state:

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed and take one action. You decide whether to move first or take your action first. Your speed — sometimes called your walking speed — is noted on your character sheet.
>
> The most common actions you can take are described in the "Actions in Combat" section later in this chapter. Many class features and other abilities provide additional options for your action.
>
> The "Movement and Position" section later in this chapter gives the rules for your move.

So your movement and your action are just totally separate things in the rules. A restriction placed on one does not by itself imply any restriction on the other.

Comment: thanks, i was hoping someone would tell me i was wrong; but anyway i appreciate the input...